# ng-repeat not working in internet explorer 8

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, razor, internet-explorer-8

To make the angular thing work on internet explorer 8 i have added the following line in my _Layout.cshtml page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org">
<html>
```

it's not working when I use `ng-repeat` it shows the expressions like

```
{{user.userName}}
```

but it's working fine if I create a plain html page just by including this line xmlns:ng...
Can anyone please help me to resolve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what version of angular are you using ?

Comment: could you also share the code? Better if in plunkr or jsfiddle

Comment: I am using AngularJS v1.2.16

Comment: @user3603255 Have you checked my answer

Comment: I already wrote there if i create a plain html file then the ng-repeat working fine in ie8 but it was not working in cshtml page MVC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will definitely work fine in IE8 with `AngularJS v1.2.16`

Check this **[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7MhLd/240/embedded/result/)** at IE 8

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7MhLd/240/light/)**

A Sample Example is shown below

**html**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="line in lines">
      <div class="preview">{{line.text}} {{$index}}</div>
   </div>
   <div ng-repeat="line in lines">
      <input ng-model="line.text"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

**script**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.lines = [{
        text: 'res1'},
    {
        text: 'res2'}];
}
```